# Do they check passport numbers at the Alhambra?

Tags: passports, tickets, spain, sightseeing

I've booked tickets to visit the [Alhambra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alhambra) in Granada. During the booking process, I had to supply the passport numbers of everyone visiting. However, my passport will have expired by the time I intend to visit, so I will have a new passport with a different number.  Will this cause me any problems when being admitted to the Alhambra, as my passport number is printed on my entrance ticket.

[image: A view of the Alhambra]

Comment: Alhambra is not an airline, it is a main sight.

Comment: @Willeke is correct,  I was asking about getting into the historic attraction, not about flying.  I can see how my wording might have been ambiguous.

Comment: If you are really concerned why not take the old one with you to show them?

Comment: Just take the old passport.  This is done so you can't (for example) sell tickets - they aren't going to care if the relevant passport is expired.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I visited the Alhambra on two different days in October 2019, and they checked the passports of almost nobody. I witnessed perhaps 50 interactions with customers showing tickets as I waited in various entry lines, and only once did they ask a visitor for their passport. I don't know what triggered the passport check for this particular customer, but he passed without issue.